# Reused Address Space in C?

Tags: c, pointers, c-strings

In a part of the program I'm working on I assign a name differently in different circumstances, but I want to keep the name either way, obviously. So I did something like so:

```
char *name;
if(*condition one*){
    char namebuilder[30] = "";
    //fill char array here
    name = namebuilder;
} else {
    name = info->name; //a char* from a struct
}

char otherstring[30] = "______________________________"
```

So basically the problem I'm having is that when the function takes the `else` route name sticks around and works just fine. But when it makes namebuilder and constructs the name, for some reason `otherstring` is ending up in the same address as name, and the name is getting overwritten with "**__________________________**". I don't understand why this is happening or how I can prevent it.

P.S: I've tested it by printing the addresses of name and otherstring, and they have the same address stored in them, but only if namebuilder was used.

Extra Background: this is a little program I'm making to mess around with pthreads, so it could possibly have to do with threading I guess, but none of the variables I mentioned are global.

EDIT: Here's the actual code for those of you asking.
    struct thread_data
    {
        char *name;
        int max;
    };

```
void* race(void* params)
{
    struct thread_data* info;
    info = (struct thread_data*)params;
    int len = strlen(info->name);
    char* name;
    if(info->max > len){
        int i;
        char newname[30] = "";
        for(i = 0; i < info->max-1; i++){
            if(i < len){
                newname[i] = info->name[i];
            } else {
                char nextchar = randChar();
                newname[i] = nextchar;    
            }
        }
        newname[info->max] = '\0';
        name = newname;
    } else {
        name = info->name;
    }
    pthread_mutex_lock(&locker);
    printf(name); //This correctly prints the name either way.
    printf(" takes off!\n");
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&locker);
    //begin trying to spell here.
    int spelt = 0;
    char spelling[30] = "______________________________";
    // All code after this sees name as "______________________________" only if it came  
    // from the if statement and not the else.
```

Comment: Um, namebuilder ceases to exist at the close brace. You are using memory after it has been freed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`namebuilder` was stored in the stack because it's local inside the if statement, after exiting the condition, it was marked as free, so when declaring `otherstring`, which have the exact same type and memory use as `namebuilder`, it took its place in the stack.

Here's how you can fix it:

```
char *name;
char namebuilder[30] = "";
if(*condition one*){
    //fill char array here
    name = namebuilder;
} else {
    name = info->name; //a char* from a struct
}

char otherstring[30] = "______________________________";
```

Answer (score 2):

Namebuilder is local to the if block. You need to lift it one scope up, or allocate it in dynamic memory with malloc() (don't forget to free() it when you're done !)

Comment: But I printed name out of the scope of that block and it works fine, but only after otherstring is declared does it change.

Comment: @Jonathan: Such is the mystery of undefined behavior.

Comment: @Jonathan As soon as namebuilder goes out of scope, the compiler is free to reuse the memory it was occupying. In your case it stores otherstring there, but name still points to it.

Answer (score 2):

Your namebuilder is local to the if block. Which means that once you leave that and try to use your `name`, accessing the memory `name` points at now is UB. You'll either have to dynamically allocate the memory for namebuilder - which means you'd have to remember to clean it up later on - or you'd have to lift the declaration of namebuilder to the scope where it's being used.